# Unable to load RegionalSettings field/property Sharepoint CSOM

Tags: c#, winforms, sharepoint, csom

```
using (ClientContext context = SharePointManager.ConnectTo(site))
{
    var spTimeZone = context.Web.RegionalSettings;
    context.Load(spTimeZone);
}
```

Error message as shown:

> "Field or property \"RegionalSettings\" does not exist

Double check with the SharePoint site that the Regional Settings is UTC +8. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably this error occurs since you are using [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585) or [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038) against SharePoint **2010** .

[Web class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web_properties(v=office.14).aspx) does **not** expose `RegionalSettings` property in SharePoint **2010** CSOM.

To summarize, it does not seem possible to retrieve Regional Settings using SharePoint 2010 CSOM since Web class does not expose `RegionalSettings` property.

**How to determine CSOM SDK assembly version?**

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ClientContext));
FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
string version = fvi.FileVersion;
```

**How to determine SharePoint version via CSOM?**

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUrl))
{
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    var version = ctx.ServerLibraryVersion;
}
```